# Appending data attribute to <a> element in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to attach data attribute to  element. My code is

```
 $('<a>', {
     class: 'like-comment 
             comment-like-color 
             comment_main_id_' + response.id,
     text: '', 
     href: 'javascript:;',
     }).appendTo(commentBody)
     .append($('<i>', {class: 'fa fa-thumbs-up'}));
```

My HTML data generated is like

```
<a class="like-comment comment-like-color 
          comment_main_id_{{$comment['id']}}" href="javascript:
          data-like-comment-id=" {{$comment[ 'id']}} ";">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

There's a **data** (data-like-comment-id) attribute, which I want to create using jQuery. Could someone please help me with it.

Comment: Add it like the other attributes in your list (text, href) or use `.attr('data-like-comment-id', 'value')`. http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between `$.fn.attr` and `$.fn.data` is:

[$.fn.attr](http://api.jquery.com/data/): stores information/data directly on the element attribute which get visible for inspection, and they are available through element's native API.

[$.fn.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/): stores info where it cannot be accessible outside JQuery and it's more closed

Data set with `attr()`

- accessible through `$(element).attr('data-name')`
- accessible through `element.getAttribute('data-name')` too
- if the value form is `data-name` it is also accessible from `$(element).data(name)` and `element.dataset['name']` and `element.dataset.name`
- Visible on element for inspection
- Cannot be objects

Data set with `.data()`

- accessible only through `.data(name)`
- Not accessible through anywhere else
- Not publicly visible for inspection
- can be objects

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29907463/6426617)

use below for `.attr()` usage

```
$('elm').attr(attname,attvalue);
```

use `data-` prefix before to avoid collision

```
$('elm').attr('data-'+attname,attvalue);
```

use below for `.data()`

```
$('elm').data(attname,attvalue);
```

Comment: This will probably work, but for data attributes the method `data()` is more flexible and offers more features

Comment: @hammus I have added some comparison depending on user need they could use it

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately I already upvoted you but if I could upvote twice I would!

Comment: Cheers mate! Hope it would help someone!

Answer (score 2):

Give your anchor element an id when you create

```
$('<a id="foo"></a>'); // Simplified for brevity
```

Then you can select it late add a data attribute with the [`$.data()` function](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
const mycomment = "some value";
$("#foo").data("like-comment", mycomment);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `attr` property

```
 $('<a>',{"class":'test',attr:{'prop':'value'}})
```

Answer (score 2):

You may just add it in your argument list on creation:

```js
 $('<a>', {
 class: 'like-comment comment-like-color comment_main_id_',
 text: '', 
 href: 'javascript:;',
 'data-like-comment-id': 'whatever'
}).appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or add it after using `.attr()`:
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

```js
$('<a>', {
    class: 'like-comment comment-like-color comment_main_id_',
    text: '', 
    href: 'javascript:;',
})
.attr('data-like-comment-id', 'whatever2')
.appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or using the `.data()` function:
https://api.jquery.com/data/

*This one wont show in the DOM*

```js
$('<a>', {
    class: 'like-comment comment-like-color comment_main_id_',
    text: '', 
    href: 'javascript:;',
})
.data('like-comment-id', 'whatever3')
.appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

for 'data-' attribute, use this

```
 $(selector).data(key, value)
```